# How to map this tricky entity/relationship model in Java?

Tags: java, database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have little bit confusing many to many relationship between 3 entities. And i want to know how can be my object model look like. I have three Entities, A,B,C and A<->B (M:N) and associate table between both, A and B, is linked with another associate table which make another 1:n relationship with third entity. I have never seen such relationship which make 1:n relationship with another associate table. For further information please have look on following diagram.

[image]

[Uploaded Image link](https://imageshack.com/)

If i talk about object model then i will say "INSTANCE_A" has many "INSTANCE_B" instance and vice versa but i do not know how can i summarize relationship  for "INSTANCE_C".

Please also let me know whether definition of such relationship between all three entities is right ? i mean is there any problem in relationship design.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: All arrows denote (1:n or m:1) relationship

Comment: i have added link to uploaded image

Comment: view image from this link http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/3/manytomany.jpg/

Comment: then can you draw an uml diagram for me  ???? because i am unable to define such relationship between instance_C and other instances of A and B. Or if such problem is described any where then quote a refrence. thanks

Comment: please say what are you trying to model. A and B NxM relationship. C?

Comment: You would just find a suitable name for many_to many tables. Try posting real model (wording like: people, system, department, company ...) instead just using TBL_A ...

Answer (score 0):

The data model is correct, but the object model for these tables can be kind of trucky. I'd do something like this:

- One class for TBL_A, with a List attribute of TBL_B
- One class for TBL_B, with a List attribute of TBL_A
- One class for TBL_C_TBL_A_B, with and an attribute for TBL_B, TBL_A and TBL_C

Mapping that in an ORM framework can get funky.

Comment: Is he asking for a mapping? I thought he wanted to model his data.

Comment: If i am not wrong, you are trying to say i should make not three classes (A,B, and C) but four (A,B,AB_C,C) and then i could be able to say c has many instance of an joined entity AB ??? am i right ?

Comment: That would be my choice. Your data model says that TBL_C is an attribute of TBL_A and TBL_B relationship, so we need an extra class to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

This shall bring you into the right direction. Try to design a UML diagram, or ER should be ok too. Here is some paper with a Model and the corresponding Java-Code for this model http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy252/references/UML_for_Java_Programmers-Book.pdf. (Go to -> Class diagrams chapter).